# Stripping out special characters

Tags: php, mysql

In the below query I am using the str_replace function to strip out '"' from some data I am parsing.  I am getting this error. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Note that line 24 has the str_replace funtion

```
 Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /public_html/Offices/update_db.php on line 24
```

Query:

```
$i = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $separator)) !== FALSE) {
    if ($i == $first_row_offset) {
        $fields = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
            $fields[$item] = $key;
        }
    } elseif ($i > $first_row_offset) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM offices_empty_locations WHERE address="' . str_replace('"', '\"',$data[$fields['addres']], 0, 250)) . '" AND zip="' . $data[$fields['zip']] . '"';
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        while ($tmp_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if (isset($tmp_data['latitude']) && $tmp_data['latitude'] > 0) {
                $query = 'UPDATE offices_main SET field_value="' . $data[$fields['lat']] . '" WHERE id=' . $tmp_data['latitude'] . ' AND field_value=""';
                mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
            }
            if (isset($tmp_data['longitude']) && $tmp_data['longitude'] > 0) {
                $query = 'UPDATE offices_main SET field_value="' . $data[$fields['lon']] . '" WHERE id=' . $tmp_data['longitude'] . ' AND field_value=""';
                mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
str_replace('"', '\"',$data[$fields['addres']], 0, 250))
                                          error ┘  │   │
                                             what? ┘   │
                                                  nooo ┘
```